# What do? __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)?

Tags: python, arguments, init

Here's the error it gives me along with the code lines specified. Apologies for past post.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Final Project\Gold Hunter.py", line 352, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Final Project\Gold Hunter.py", line 346, in main
    score = game()
  File "H:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Final Project\Gold Hunter.py", line 195, in game
    pirate = Pirate()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

**ACTUAL CODE**

```
  main() Line 352
  score = game() Line 346
  pirate = Pirate() Line 195
```

**Pirate Constructor** It gives me the error NameError: global name 'dx' is not defined

```
class Pirate(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    EAST = 0

    def __init__(self, screen, dx):
        self.screen = screen
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("king_pirate/running e0000.bmp")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        tranColor = self.image.get_at((1, 1))
        self.image.set_colorkey(tranColor)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.inflate_ip(-50, -30)
        self.rect.center = (0, random.randrange(30,450))
        self.img = []

        self.loadPics()
        self.frame = 0
        self.delay = 4
        self.pause = self.delay
        self.dx = dx
```

Comment: Please add the constructor for `Pirate`. You need to provide two arguments to the constructor when you create a new `Pirate` instance.

Comment: How come you did not see ANY duplicates here?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lee's comment. We cannot see the `class Pirate:` constructor but it is clear that your `__init__` function is taking THREE arguments when you define it. These would be `self, argument1, argument2`, so when you call `pirate = Pirate()` on line 195, you must actually provide it 2 arguments (it will get `self` on its own). You need to give it the argument1 and argument2 that you defined in the constructor. Post the constructor for more help. Your line 195 should look something like `pirate = Pirate(argument1, argument2)`

Good Luck!